# How to concatenate two streams using gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, concatenation

For example I have a task with next content:

```
function task() {
    gulp.src('libs/*.js')
        // some manipulations
        .concat('libs.js')

    gulp.src('js/*.js')
        // Another manipulations
        .concat('app.js')
}
```

What if I don't want to put this files anywhere in file system? Can I somehow concatenate `libs.js` and `app.js` inside a task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [***merge-stream***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) package. Simple example:

```
gulp.task("do-something", function() {
    var vendorScripts1 = gulp.src("libs/*.js")
        .pipe(/* I want to do something*/));

    var vendorScripts2 = gulp.src("js/*.js")
        .pipe(/* I want to do something else here*/);

    return merge(vendorScripts1 , vendorScripts2)
      .pipe(/*bla bla bla*/);
});
```

[`Github example`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md) I hope it will help you.

Thanks